# Training a network with data having high and low values

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am using Torch on Pyhton to train a network that approximates a complicated mathematic expression, i.e., for a 2D-input, I need a `K` length vector that is computed using the 2D-input using some mathematical calculations. However, in this vector, there are values (absolute) of the order of `10^2` and also values of the order of `10^-5`. The minimum value and maximum value are dependent on the input and a common normalization cannot be used. I have normalized the input to be between `0` and `1`. I have tried using mask while training using the following snippet.

```
import torch
import numpy as np

gnd_truth = torch.from_numpy(np.array([20.42, -1.56e-4, -3.11, 4.2e-2, -7e-3, 10.11]))[None]  # Ground truth
dnn_in = torch.from_numpy(np.array([0.76, 0.34]))[None]  # Input to the network

# Training 
optimizer.zero_grad()

dnn_out = net(dnn_in)  # Forward prop

mask = (torch.abs(gnd_truth) < 1e-2).float() * 100  # Multiplying by 100 to increase the value

loss = mse_loss(mask*dnn_out, gnd_truth) + mse_loss((1-mask)*dnn_out, (1-mask)*gnd_truth)

loss.backward()

optimizer.step()
```

This too did not give me the desired result. Can anyone please let me know on how such a training can be carried out?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is also included in the things you already tried, it seems that your problem could be solved by predicting log(K) instead of K, and using exponential afterwards. Using base 10 log, your values would range from 2 to -5, which seems reasonable, and using the global min and max you could also normalize these log-values to [0,1] if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as I have shown, my values also contain negatives. log of negative values is not defined. I have edited the text to highlight this now.

Comment: Oh sorry, i did not notice it. Maybe predicting log(|X|) and separately a binary value for the sign then ? This might be a bit harder since the loss is not as straightforward to compute though

Answer (score 0):

You can try to predict the log of the values as well as a multiplicative factor between -1 and 1. Then you can keep the original GT values but make a change in the model and loss:

```py
log_dnn_out, factor = net(dnn_in)
loss = mse_loss(torch.tanh(factor)*torch.exp(log_dnn_out), gnd_truth)
```

I hope that the `exp` will not perturb the gradient too much.
If it is the case you can do a MSE on log and a separate binary classification for sign:

```py
log_dnn_out, sign_logits = net(dnn_in)
loss_log = mse_loss(log_dnn_out, torch.abs(torch.log(gnd_truth)))
loss_sgn = cross_entropy(sign_logits, (torch.sign(gnd_truth)+1) // 2)
loss = loss_log + a*loss_sgn
```

This option is safer regarding gradients but introduces learning biases that are potentially non desired by splitting the main task in two sub-tasks.